# Should the context of SQLiteOpenHelper always be the running activity?

Tags: android

I want to open the `database` once only from the main screen of my app , and I want to use this instance anywhere in any `activity`. Is that possible or should I make the `context` to be each actual opened `activity` so that I must create an instance of the database ( open ) in every `activity` ?

Comment: Do this from Service or Application subclass (ApplicationContext), that way, you'll have the connection and lock/synchronisation available in any Activity

Comment: can you explain more clearly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that possible or should I make the context to be each actual opened
>   activity so that I must create an instance of the database ( open ) in
>   every activity ?

it is possible, and you could use the application context. Your `DBHelper` could be a singleton. E.g

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

  private static DBHelper sInstance;
  public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {    
    if (sInstance == null) {
       sInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
  }

  private DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

}
```

Comment: it isn't unused ... *look closer*

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to close and re-open the SQL connection per each individual `Activity`.

Having said that - it is best to open the connection using an app context, to avoid [Activity leaks](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html).

You can get an app context refrence [quite easily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002288/static-way-to-get-context-on-android).